# Does Windows XP connection limit apply to Sql Server connections?

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp

I have installed Sql Server 2005 on Windows XP acting as server in a small workgroup. Since XP has as limit of 10 computers connecting at the same time, my question is, does this limit also apply to concurrent connections over TCP/IP to the Sql Server? Or does this limit only apply to connections to shares, printers and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882) states maximum of 10 connections.

> For Windows XP Professional, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is ten. This limit includes all transports and resource sharing protocols combined. For Windows XP Home Edition, the maximum number of other computers that are permitted to simultaneously connect over the network is five. This limit is the number of simultaneous sessions from other computers the system is permitted to host

Although

> The connection limit refers to the number of redirector-based connections and is enforced for any file, print, named pipe, or mail slot session. The TCP connection limit is not enforced, but it may be bound by legal agreement to not permit more than 10 client

[These people](http://forums.techarena.in/tips-tweaks/4751.htm) seem to have copied or created a tcpip driver that enables up to 50 connections.

It is not clear to me if they took TCPIP.SYS from another microsoft operating system or if they somehow wrote their own.

Comment: In other words: yes the limit applies, but it won't be enforced and will probably work anyway?

Comment: That is my impression.